# for some users, Tibco spotfire dashboard can't locate source Sas data on shared drive

Tags: sas, tibco

I saved some SAS datasets on our shared drive and created a Spotfire dashboard which i saved in the shared drive and and also published in the library. 
The tibco spotfire dashboards read these data sets as data sources. the data is linked and not embedded to the dashboard.

I have tested it with my colleagues and they were able to open the dashboard. 
However other users can't open the dashboard as it says it can't locate the source file.

Comment: Please be more specific: what is the role of SAS and of typco? What did you try?
Preferable add code examples (or screen shots)

Comment: @DirkHorsten in summary what i do is; create sas data sets which i save onto our shared drive, the tibco spotfire dashboards read these  data sets as data sources. the data is linked and not embedded to the dashboard. when other users try to open the dashboards it says ''the following file cannot be found'' pointing to the source file (which exists in the shard drive and the file path is correct)

Comment: what is the exact error message?